# Given a set of 2D points (x,y) (cloud of points), find the points that, when connected, will contain all other points

Tags: geometry, algorithms, coordinate-systems, signal-processing

Given a set of 2D points I have to find the points that when connected will form a polygon that contains all the points in the set.

A quick example: imagine you have a set `S={(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(2,2),(4,4)}`.

The solution would be `SolS={(1,1),(2,1),(1,2),(4,4)}` as those points (when connected) form a polygon that cointains all the points in the set (`(2,2)` is cointained inside the polygon).

Here is a diagram describing the problem :
[image]

And the Solution (Sorry for the quick scketeches):                [image]

Now, this obviously need to be extended to deal with `n` 2D points.

I have been cracking my head trying to work out an algorithm but I just cant find it.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word for what you are describing is the **convex hull** of the points. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) has a list of algorithms for computing them.

Comment: @Zebs: No problem!

Comment: Thank you, I was actually looking for a concave hull but this pointed me in the right direction!!!!!